# Summing Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample table

```
create table #t (id int,qty int)
insert into #t values(1,100),(2,200),(3,150),(4,50)
```

I am trying to get this

```
id        qty       total_qty
1   100 100
2   200 300
3   150 450
4   50  500
```

this is not working

```
select a.id,a.qty,sum(b.qty) as total_qty from #t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2012, you can do this directly:

```
select a.id, a.qty, sum(a.qty) over (order by a.id) as total_qty
from #t a;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can do this with a correlated subquery or non-equijoin.  Below is an example:

```
select t.id, t.qty,
       (select sum(t2.qty) from #t t2 where t2.id <= t.id) as total_qty
from #t t;
```

EDIT:

The expression `sum(a.qty) over (order by a.id)` is a window function that expresses a cumulative sum.  The `over` is saying "do something for each row".  What it does for each row is take the sum of `a.qty`.  But, not just any sum, a sum that takes the ordering into account.  The `order by` is what makes this a cumulative sum.  (Without the `order by` clase, `sum(a.qty) over ()` would return the sum of from all the rows, as an additional column in each row.)

Comment: Can you tell me how sum() over () works ! I understand using cross join !

Answer (score 1):

Use a join !

```
select a.id,a.qty,sum(b.qty) as total_qty from #t a cross join #t b where b.id<=a.id
group by a.id,a.qty
order by a.id
```

## [see Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14742)

Comment: You're probably better off _not_ using a `CROSS JOIN` (with correlation in the `WHERE` clause), and just using a regular `JOIN`.  The optimizer may be doing that for you anyways, but it'd be better to make it clear in your statement.

Comment: ya ! a regular join must do it or just `sum() over()` --as above !